# jquery clone object issue

Tags: jquery, clone

I am cloning following div and I want to create newids on every clone. and it is doing like that but it is creating div as separate and inputs as separate out side div and all design messup. I want following div_ clone withall inputs should appear in other div container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_" style="display: none;" class="well form-inline">
    <label>Label :</label>    <input type="text"  id="txtlabel" name="txtlabel" />
    <label>value :</label>    <input type="text"  id="txtvalue" name="txtvalue" />
    <label>Selected :</label> <input type="checkbox" name="chk_sel" value="chk_sel" />
    <label>Required :</label> <input type="checkbox" name="chk_isreq" value="chk_isreq" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var = question_cnt=1;
$("#div_").clone().find("input,label").andSelf().each(function() {
    $(this).show();
    $(this).attr('id', this.id +question_cnt );
    $(this).attr('name', this.name +question_cnt );
}).appendTo("#container").end();
question_cnt++;
```

Comment: For starters, you're creating duplicate id's. question_cnt is not changed for every iteration of each()

Comment: thats not a issue, ids are unique on every clone issue is inputs are appearing out side of div_. inputs should be in div_.

Comment: If they're meant to appear inside `div_`, why are you appending them to `#container`?

Comment: Really? Duplicate id's are definitely an issue in your code (although I'm not saying that your problem is caused by that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably what you're trying to do, although I'm puzzled by looping through the `label`s too? They don't have `id`'s or `name`'s, or even `for`'s, which would make sense. Why loop over those?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $underscore = $("#div_"),
        question_cnt = 0;

    function clone() {
        var $clone = $underscore.clone();

        $clone
            .find("input, label")
            .each(function() {
                $(this)
                    .attr({
                        id: this.id + question_cnt,
                        name: this.name + question_cnt
                    });       
            });

        $clone
            .appendTo("#container")
            .show();

        question_cnt++;
    }

    $('#cloneit').click(clone);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/M2xjp/

Comment: Looking at it, how do think you would? I can tell you, but try first. Then I'll give an answer. And what is the deal with the `label` attributes?

Comment: $clone.attr('id', this.id + question_cnt ); this is working fine. and label was added just mistakenly :). thanks for your help.

Comment: Not quite. Take a look at the handler again.

Comment: but what was wrong with my code why it was putting div_ as seperate and inputs as seperate ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/M2xjp/1/ `this.id` in the `clone()` handler context points at the `button`, not the `$clone`. You were trying to pack too much action into one little block. Don't get worked up about chaining like mad and "doing it all in one line". Lay your code out where you can read it and do bite-sized things a step at a time.

Comment: <div id="cloneit0" style="" class="well form-inline"><div id="cloneit1" style="" class="well form-inline"> whats wrong with this apparently it is looking ok.

Comment: That's not right; `cloneit` is from the `button`'s `id` attribute.

Comment: $clone.attr('id', $clone.attr("id") + question_cnt );i totally missed that i m getting wrong ids. thanks for ur help.